# Flutter, IOS, TextFormField maxLines issue

Tags: flutter

```
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: ctrler_txtEdt_for_address,
                autofocus: false,
                maxLines: 1,
                minLines: 1,
```

I have a text field where user need to copy paste an address.

But in Apple Maps, the address seems to contain \n. (Not in Google Maps) Even though maxLines is set to 1, it is copied and pasted in multiple lines. I also don't know how this is possible. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to the `TextEditingController` and use the `.trim` method when data is input.

Comment: Yes, but is it not possible to force it to be only 1 line within the TextFormField itself? I am wondering why this issue occurs and if there is no way to fix it. As a follow-up, I also did the work of replacing \n with an empty space.

Comment: remove `minLines` and test again. ig using both parameters here is the issue